# CSS Animations lagging on Android devices

Tags: javascript, android, css

I have some problems with rendering animation on my nextjs app with a tailwind. Namely, I have just a simple animation that makes the logo smaller on scroll, but it seems it lags on Android devices. I have tested from 2 different iPhones, a few laptops and three android phones (Samsung Note10, Flex 4 and some Xioami). Only on android happens that is lagging.

So what I'm doing is (first check scroll position) (it shouldn't be a problem)

```
 useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', stickNavbar);
        return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', stickNavbar);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        offsetX < 1024 ? offsetY > 40 ? setScroll(true) : setScroll(false) : undefined
        offsetX >= 1024 ? offsetY > 76 ? setScroll(true) : setScroll(false) : undefined
    }, [offsetY, offsetX])

    const stickNavbar = () => {
        if (window !== undefined) {
            setOffsetY(window.scrollY)
            setOffsetX(screen.width)
        }
    };
```

and ofc, I'm checking when position is true to assign the class. I made my CSS class in order to test those performance issues:

```
${scroll ? 'w-8 scrolled' : ''}
```

So here is the final CSS:

```
.nav {
  .logo{
    //transition-delay: 0.15s;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    top: -1.5rem;

    &.scrolled{
      margin-top: 2.15rem;
      margin-left: 0.75rem;
    }

    @include desktop(){
      transition-delay: 0s;
    }
  }
}
```

As you see, I have commented delay; causing a delay could be a possible fix to avoid that much lag. But is there any other things that I should look for?

Here is the demo of the app [enter link description here](https://kgb.gg)